# calculator in c++ adding function

Tags: c++

So my program makes a random `(x,y)` arrays, what i want to do is to make `x` a real number and `y` imaginary number and add them:
my main program

```
    #include "complx.h"                          
    int main(){
    const int n = 2;
    Complex a[n];                          
    getData(a,n);
    printArray(a,n);
    isort(a,n);
    printArray(a,n);
    complex_sum(a,n);
    return 0;
}
```

it also prints and arranges the arrays, but what I am interested in is how to add the arrays, when for example I would use 4 arrays `(x,y)(x,y)(x,y)(x,y)`.

this is how i get a random numbers

```
    void getData(Complex a[],int n){
    int  i;
    srand(time(0)); //If comment this out, get same sequence with each run.      
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        a[i].x = rand()%3;  //3 and 10 are just for testing isort                
        a[i].y = rand()%10;
    }
    return;
}
```

and here is how i'm trying to add it:

```
void complex_sum(Complex a[], int n){
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
      cout<<"("<<a[i].x+a[i].x<<")";
    cout<<endl;
    return;
```

I am stuck on how to add `(x,y)(x,y)= x+yi`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am not completely inline with the way you are attempting; but** to sum `n` number of `complex numbers` stored in an array and print it on screen you can try the following:

```
void complex_sum(Complex a[], int n){
    int real=0,img=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        real+=a[i].x;
        img+=a[i].y;
    }
    cout<<"("<<real << "+" << img << "i)";
}
```